# java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization: when resolving method

Tags: java, web-services

I have developed a web service with authentication in java following the link [Web Service Atuthentication](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/application-authentication-with-jax-ws/)
The Same is runing fine if I am using JDK 1.6/JBoss 4.2 but when I deploy it in Jboss 5.1.0 GA I am getting deployment error. I google and found there is some jar conflict between JDK1.6,Jboss and my application. And replaced the JBoss/lib/endorsed jaxws-ri.jar with the latest jaxws-ri-2.2.8.jar. But I am not able to identify which jar is creating conflict now.

Below is my code of web.xml, sun-jaxws.xml and exception.

```
web.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>biservices</display-name>
<listener>
<listener-class>
        com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>BiServices</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>BiServices</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/biservices</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
<session-timeout>120</session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>


sun-jaxws.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoints xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime" version="2.0">
<endpoint
   name="IBiUpdate"
   implementation="com.sbilife.ws.BiUpdate"
   url-pattern="/biservices"/>
</endpoints>

exception
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization: when resolving method "com.sun.xml.ws.util.xml.XMLStreamReaderFilter.getAttributeName(I)Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;" the class loader (instance of org/jboss/classloader/spi/base/BaseClassLoader) of the current class, com/sun/xml/ws/util/xml/XMLStreamReaderFilter, and the class loader (instance of <bootloader>) for interface javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader have different Class objects for the type javax/xml/namespace/QName used in the signature
```

Thanks
Pise

Comment: Do you have multiple jars deployed within JBoss that contain javax/xml/namespace/QName?

Comment: @Caleryn but how to find which jar.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/tg123/3897887 run this python script in your `web-inf/lib` to see which jar is dup

Comment: farmer1992 thanks for code, Caleryn but I found a way in eclipse to search classes inside jar files, actually I thought that search would not be looking into the jar classes but it even search inside jar. What exactly to search XMLStreamReaderFilter.getAttributeName(I) method or javax/xml/namespace/QName because one of my friend told me that getAttributeName(I) is creating a conflict and this class is found in jaxws-rt.jar only. When I search javax/xml/namespace/QName there is not match.

Answer (score 1):

The exception is thrown because in your web application at least exists a jar which contains the `javax.xml.namespace.QName` class and that class conflicts with the same one contained in one of the JBoss's jar.

You should remove that (these) jar(s) from your web application when deploying on JBoss.

A list of jars which contain the `javax.xml.namespace.QName` class is at http://www.findjar.com/class/javax/xml/namespace/QName.html